# Sqlserver Number needs to be convert as integer

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have data as below,

```
Id    EmpName   Amt
101   AAA       100.0000
102   BBB       -
```

If Amt is number i need to display 100(without decimal point) or I need to display as it is.

Expected o/p,

```
Id    EmpName   Amt
101   AAA       100
102   BBB       -
```

I used below but getting exception,

```
select id, empname, (CASE WHEN amt NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%' then amt else left(CONVERT(varchar(50), CAST(ROUND(amt,0) AS money), 1),len(CONVERT(varchar(50), CAST(ROUND(amt,0) AS money), 1)) - 3) end ) 
            as ff,
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `TRY_CAST`:

```
SELECT id, empname, ROUND(TRY_CAST(Amt AS DECIMAL(18,4)),0) AS amt
FROM tab
```

Comment: @AjayGupta It depends. If OP wants original value then yes, but in his CASE statement there was no explicit `ELSE` part so any value that cannot be converted will end up as `NULL`.

Comment: I want in Sqlserver. Try_cast not reconized. Im using sqlserver 2008

Answer (score 0):

I would use `try_convert()`:

```
select id, empname,
       (case when try_convert(decimal(18, 0), amt)
             then convert(varchar(255), convert(decimal(18, 0), amt))
             else amt
        end) as ff
. . .
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
Select id, empname, CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(amt) = 1 AND amt NOT IN ('-','+','$','.',',','\') 
                         THEN CAST(Round(CAST(amt as float),0) as varchar(50)) 
                         ELSE amt END as amt 
FROM tbl
```